# can ping the server but not able to access

Tags: network, server, ping

i am able to ping the server machine named "tallyserver" which is windows server 2003 machine configured with automatically IP address setting but when i am going to Network, sometimes it shows the machine and some times not. when i click the "tallyserver" or accessing by it's IP address, it shows me message saying "windows cannot access \192.168.0.102" with error code "0x800004005".

And when i am accessing the other PCs shared in same network there is no problem. i can access them easily.

one more thing is that as i am encounter this problem since 3/4 days. i have to use Remote Desktop Connection to work on the server and i can login and do the work by using Remote Desktop Connection.

but i need to access it directly without using Remote Desktop Connection.

After diagnose the message i got is as below, sharing if it helps you to understand the situation.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Windows Network Diagnostics
Issues found
Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (tall... Detected
Make sure that the device or resource (tallyserver) allows inc... Completed
Issues found
< Windows can't communicate with the device or resource
(tallyserver)
Detected
It is available but is not responding to connection attempts. A firewall or
network security policy on the remote computer might be blocking the
connection on port "file and print sharing resource".
Make sure that the device or resource (tallyserver) allows
incoming connections for File and Printer Sharing
Completed
Windows Help and Support can provide more information about Windows
Firewall.
Detection details
Network Diagnostics Log
File Name: 93440B71-1AE0-49FA-A444-3E9E9349C3CE.Diagnose.0.etl
Other Networking Configuration and Logs
File Name: NetworkConfiguration.cab
Collection information
Computer Name: DPK-PC
Windows Version: 10.0
Architecture: x64
Time: Tuesday, June 19, 2018 11:49:47 AM
Publisher details
Windows Network Diagnostics
Detects problems with network connectivity.
Package Version: 4.0
Publisher: Microsoft Windows

---

the firewall of server is off. and i uninstall the antivirus also but still the same problem persist.

Please Help

Thank You

Comment: Welcome, Deepak! Unfortunately, I do not believe that your question is fit for our site. This site is for security questions, the fact you cannot get to a server via RDP is not a security question, it's tech-support.

Comment: This is a network and not a security question, i.e. off-topic. ping works at another level than than file sharing, and one might work while the other not. It might just be that file sharing is disabled, that some firewall is inferring with the connection or similar.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @SteffenUllrich
but i turned firewall off and share the drive properly

Comment: Hi Deepak, You may post this at Server Fault section of Stack Exchange (https://serverfault.com/) - You'll be able to get help there and that would be the suitable site for network/server related questions...